# Is it possible to create branch type on gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, bitbucket

Previously I used bitbucket. And I move to GitLab. Is it possible to create a branch type on GitLab?

branch type like this:

[image]

Comment: You can name branches like "feature/yourbranchname"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, GitLab does not support [branch types](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-branches-in-bitbucket-server-776639968.html#UsingbranchesinBitbucketServer-Branchtypes) or branching models supported by Bitbucket. You can only manually set branch names with proper prefixes or suffixes.

Comment: like this `bugs/bug-fix-01`?

Comment: Default branching model seems to be `bugfix/<branch name>` but according to docs you can change the model according to your needs.